# Adobe DTM and JW Player tags only iterate through the first video

Tags: jwplayer, adobe-analytics

Can anyone provide me with help as to how to get this code to work on the next selected video in jw carousel?

```
var newVideo = ["video1", "video2", "video3", "video4"];
function trackVideo(){
// video start
jwplayer().onPlay(function(event){
 _satellite.track("videostart");
 console.log("onPlay");
 });
}
trackVideo(newVideo)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is on an internal server.

Comment: Can you put up a test page externally? I need to see something to debug properly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the assistance.  I expanded the code and corrected it with a for loop, it works perfectly.  The original code is from [here](http://www.maassmedia.com/blog/tracking-jwplayer-you-tube-flash-videos-dtm/)

I needed to modify it slightly to work with a jwplayer playlist as opposed to a single video (all in adobe DTM: the actual tags are excluded and I'm using cosnole.log to return a value)...Thanks and here it is..

```
//
var newVideo = ["video1", "video2", "video3", "video4", "video5", "video6", "video7", "video8"];
function trackVideo(a){
for(var i = 0, l = a.length; i < l; i++){
// video start
jwplayer(a[i]).onPlay(function(event){
  _satellite.track("videostart");
 console.log("onPlay");
 });
// video stop, pause
 jwplayer(a[i]).onPause(function(event){
  _satellite.track("videopause");
 console.log("onPause");
 });
 // video complete
 jwplayer(a[i]).onComplete(function(event){
  _satellite.track("videocomplete");
 console.log("onComplete");
 });
  // video timer fires the direct call rule halfway through the video
 jwplayer(a[i]).onTime(function(event) {
 if (event.position == parseInt(jwplayer().getDuration()/2)) {
 _satellite.track("videofiftypercent");
 console.log("onTime");
 }
 });
   // video timer fires the direct call rule quarter through the video
 jwplayer(a[i]).onTime(function(event) {
 if (event.position == parseInt(jwplayer().getDuration()/4)) {
 _satellite.track("videotwentyfivepercent");
 console.log("onTimeTwentyFive");
 }
 });
}
}
trackVideo(newVideo);
```